# How to wrap an external HTTP data source in HTTPS?

Tags: http, ssl, https, rss

I'm consuming an RSS feed that is only served over HTTP. I am using it in a static website. I want to serve my website over HTTPS without mixed content. Other than creating a small API to consume then re-expose the RSS data, are there any other options to wrapping this HTTP RSS feed into an HTTPS RSS feed?

Comment: HTTP(S) proxy. You can probably use your own web server for that purpose with minimal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I used this tool to fix my issue: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/